# How to name tables which are responsible for storing dictionaries and configuration?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, naming-convention, sql-server-2019

Below I attached diagram which corresponds to part of my database :

[image]

My questions:

1. In your opininon Do I have to divide `ServiceInsance` and `ConfServiceInstance` ? I did it like that because I would like to have separated IDs and Configuration columns.
2. What do you think about name of these tables ? I mean Is it worth to have `Dict` and `Conf` in table names ?
3. Is it a problem that `PK` does not corespond to table name by convention: TableName + ID in `Conf` and `Dict` tables ?
4. Is it a better idea to create schemas `conf` and `dict` maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

I would have 3 tables "Service", "ServiceInstance", and "Node".  1-1 relationships are generally best collapsed into a single table, and there's no reason to decorate your lookup tables with a a prefix.

Comment: This. By definition the non-key columns in a table are describing the entity - e.g. the ServiceInstance - so you usually don't need a prefix to say it's 'configuration'. In the database it's not a Dictionary, it's a table, which by definition stores multiple rows of that entity. You also don't want to name your tables based on your app's data structure implementation, e.g. you might change that sometime. Usually if you model the tables based on the real-world entities things work out well: hence Service, ServiceInstance and Node.